# subgroup analysis - how many patients in subgroups are sufficient to make it meaningful?

Tags: statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics, multilevel-analysis, small-sample, clinical-trials

In Clinical trials, subgroup analyses are often planned based on demographics and baseline characteristics. Sometimes the subgroups may have only a few patients, so the question is how many patients in subgroups will make it statistically meaningful? 
Assuming we are not doing comparison between subgroups, so only give some descriptive statistics on subgroups.

Is n>=20 in the smallest subgroup a rule of thumb?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly you want to do with these subgroups?

Comment: We want to look at the responses in different subgroups. The responses can be time to event variables, biomarker changes from baseline, or QoL change from baseline. The subgroups can be gender, age group, region, disease stage, chemo-naive or non chemo-naive, etc.

Comment: I understand that but am confused why you tagged your question with `multilevel-analysis`. How does the multilevel come into play?

Comment: Subgroup sample size depends on many issues. If the analysis is hypothesis generating, then no minimum sample is needed. If you want to make independent inferences, then you may need to compute a specific sample size for superiority testing. Otherwise, you may be happy with an overall significant value and an subgroup interaction test.